# Android - How can I trigger a validation for an edittext field

Tags: android, validation, triggers, android-edittext

I need to implement an edittext field that just allows user input from 20 to 60. If user input a number that is out of range, a dialog will display and force user to input again.

So the text watcher is not useful because it cannot prevent user input a number that lower than 20.

The onFocusChangedListener is neither, if user clicks on 'done' button, the edittext doesn't lost focus, so the trigger doesn't fire as well.

Besides, the edittext is inside a tab view, so when user clicks on another tab, the trigger fires but user cannot input value for that edittext any more.

Answer (score 2):

Alvin is right ... this is my code to do something with text once entered, but could have as easily been a validation sequence:

```
smsMsgBody_editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        // Do something fancy
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) { }
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) { }
});
```

Comment: @Alvin Then, @Jaydeep Khamar. As I did mention in my question, the text watcher is not useful for the case user input is lower than 20. Such as when user input 8 and click on 'done' button or move to another tab, the text watcher cannot help, right?

Comment: You can absolutely use the code above to do validation.  You can also validate your fields by adding a method call to your onClick() for the "done" button or the same for tabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(new OnTabChangeListener(){
            public void onTabChanged(String tabId) {
                doValidation();
            }});

Comment: Currently, I do that way, however, there are more items're around it such as action bar, menu bar, so I need to put my validation inside those items that's not so nice... I am looking for a better solution if any.

Answer (score 1):

How about keeping track of the EditText field with onTextChanged?

Comment: Make sure you handle the delete key being pressed while the `EditText` is empty: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13983097/832776

Answer (score 1):

use these

```
android:maxLength="2" android:numeric="integer"
```

then when you get the number like: number.gettext() you make validations like if number>60 and lower then 20 you can do `number.setHint("number no valid");`

Comment: thanks subspider, but the problem is how to fire the validation