# Android: EditText Validation with TextWatcher and .setError()

Tags: android, validation, android-edittext, textwatcher

I have implemented a simple validation for a `TextEdit` using this code:

```
    title = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.title);
    title.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
             if (title.getText().length() < 1) {
                    title.setError( "Title is required" );
               } else {
                    title.setError(null); 
               }
            
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            
        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                int count) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            
        }
    });
```

The function checks if there is any text inserted on a `textchange` and everything works perfectly, until I put my cursor in the already empty title field, and press delete once more. the error message gets reset and the `textwatcher` is not called, because there is no text change. How can I even display the error message in this case?

Comment: text watcher is getting called. But in already empty text field, if you hit delete key, notice that there is no text change and therefore afterTextChanged will not be called.

Comment: Found a solution! See my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to also override the `onKeyUp` method (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.Callback.html).  In there, check to see if the key pressed was `KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DEL`, then also check to see if the text in the EditText is empty.  If it is, throw your error.

Comment: Good suggestion but KeyEvents are discouraged for soft inputs.
"there is no guarantee that any key press on a soft keyboard will generate a key event, this is left to the IME's discretion, the default software keyboard will never send any key event to any application targeting Jelly Bean or later, and will only send events for SOME presses of the delete and return keys to applications targeting Ice Cream Sandwich or earlier"
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.html

Comment: Interesting, I hadn't seen that.  If that's the case, I'm not entirely sure OP can accomplish what they want.

Comment: too bad, but thanks for your try! i gave up and just implemented a simple check on submit...

Answer (score 0):

It seems that internally `TextView` has a flag and calls `setError(null)` if the keyboard sends a key command but the text remains the same. So I subclassed `EditText` and implemented `onKeyPreIme()` to swallow the delete key if the text is "". Just use `EditTextErrorFixed` in your XML files:

```
package android.widget;

import android.content.Context;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.KeyEvent;

public class EditTextErrorFixed extends EditText {
    public EditTextErrorFixed(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public EditTextErrorFixed(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public EditTextErrorFixed(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    /**
     * Don't send delete key so edit text doesn't capture it and close error
     */
    @Override
    public boolean onKeyPreIme(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(getText().toString()) && keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DEL)
            return true;
        else
            return super.onKeyPreIme(keyCode, event);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the latest textInputLayout and textInputEditText for better results-
https://material.io/components/text-fields/android

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/29990776)