# Change EditText.setError() background and error message android

Tags: android, android-edittext

I want to change the text and background color of error message for invalid email address. I tried but my text message doesn't display any content. here is my code.

```
public class TextboxValidation {


    //validating email address

    public static boolean validateEditText(EditText editText) {
        boolean valid = true;
        Context context;

        String text = editText.getText().toString();

        boolean isEmail = (editText.getInputType() & InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_EMAIL_ADDRESS) == InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_EMAIL_ADDRESS;
        boolean isNumeric = (editText.getInputType() & InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_DECIMAL) == InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_DECIMAL;

        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(text)) {
            if (!isNumeric || !TextUtils.isDigitsOnly(editText.getHint())) {
                valid = false;
            }

        } else if (isEmail) {
            valid = android.util.Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(text).matches();
        }

        if (!valid) {
            context = editText.getContext();

            if (isEmail) {

                int ecolor = R.color.black; // whatever color you want
                String estring = "Veuillez saisir une addresse email valide";
                ForegroundColorSpan fgcspan = new ForegroundColorSpan(ecolor);
                SpannableStringBuilder ssbuilder = new SpannableStringBuilder(estring);
                ssbuilder.setSpan(fgcspan, 0, estring.length(), 0);

                editText.setError(ssbuilder);
            } else {
                editText.setError("Le champ ne peut etre vide.");
            }
            return false;
        }

        editText.setError(null);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5232885/1168654

Comment: [This](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=10378) answer should help you to resolve the issue

Comment: Check this my answer : http://stackoverflow.com/a/18974425/1318946

Answer (score 0):

You can change the text color by using **HTML Font Tag.**

But for customizing background color, you should make your own custom pop up.
For more information, Kindly go through this link:- 
[How to write style to error text of EditText in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14413575/how-to-write-style-to-error-text-of-edittext-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this.

```
if (TextUtils.isEmpty(cashierid)) {
        cid.setError(Html.fromHtml("<font color='red'>Username can't be empty</font>"));
        return;
    }
else if (TextUtils.isEmpty(cashierpwd)) {
        cpwd.setError(Html.fromHtml("<font color='red'>Password can't be empty</font>"));
        return;
    }
```