# Error-popup in EditText is not showing?

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

I have an *EditTextField* with a *DatepickerListener* on it. If I press a submit button it should validate that field and if they are empty it should show an error message. To display this error message I use the `EditText.setError()` method but the popup doesnt show. I dont know how to fix it.

I tested it on 2 Devices. Once with a OnePlus 5 on Android 7.1.1 and once on a Samsung Galaxy 7 on Android 7.0.0. Same behaviour on both devices.

Thank you in Advance.

Here is my Code (Dummy Version):

```
private void initRequestButton(View view) {
    Button button = view.findViewById(R.id.submitButton);
    EditText dateTextField = view.findViewById(R.id.someField);        

    button.setOnClickListener(v -> {
        String dateText = dateTextField.getText().toString();
        if (dateText.isEmpty()) {
                dateTextField.setError("A date is required");
        } else {
            //do Something
        }
    });
}
```

**The Layout**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
app:errorEnabled="true">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="10dip"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/someField"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dip"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:cursorVisible="false"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:inputType="none" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="10dip"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/submitButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="0.3"
        android:text="@string/someText" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: try putting the focus into your editText before set the error.

Comment: Have a look at [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13414473/android-edittext-seterror-doesnt-work-as-expected).

Comment: @ADM the error icon shows up and keeps staying there but I get no message displayed. Thats my point

Comment: @canillas i tried that too but it doesn't work either

Comment: Yeah i know it . on which device what Apilevel ? Try to test it on Other devices too . and let us know here .

Comment: Currently Im testing it on Android 7.1.1 on a OnePlus 5.**Update** I tested it now on a Samsung S7 which is on version 7.0 and it didnt work either

Answer (score 3):

Just remove the

```
 android:focusable="false"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
```

properties from the edittext.

Comment: This works only partly. I had these two components to disable the softkeyboard and to disable the typing on these two edit texts.

Answer (score 0):

The code you are using to set error is alright, but the popup pops only when the edittext is focussed either by touching manually or by programmatically, just add,

```
yourEdtext.requestFocus()
```

after setting error to the field. This will show the popup after validation fails

Comment: It does not work the error message is still not showing up. It only shows the red alert sign but not the message.

Comment: Have you tried removing all the focuss tags in your xml?

Comment: In  your xml , I can see some unnecessary code, you have used clickable=false, inputtype=none. Even if you don't want this field editable, this not the good way to do it for sure. Instead, remove those tags and in your java class, use code,  edText.setKeyListener = null

Comment: Mhh i did that and it still doesn't work. I agree that has the same effect but the popup still doesnt show up.

Comment: is it showing the pop up when you click the edittext?

Comment: No it is not. It is opening the Datepicker popup.