# EditText error not cleared

Tags: android, android-edittext

Let's take the following reduced test case:

**`activity_main.xml`**:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@android:id/text1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@android:id/text2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Click me!"
        android:id="@android:id/button1"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

**`MainActivity.xml`**:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        final TextView text1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text1);
        final TextView text2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text2);
        Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    text1.setError("error");
                    text2.setError("error");
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

I have the following problem: the the documentation of `TextView.setErrorText()` says the error message and icon is cleared when any key events cause changes to the `TextView`. But in this example, only the second widget is cleared, the first is not when changed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation is very clear on it:

`public void setError (CharSequence error)`

"Sets the right-hand compound drawable of the TextView to the "error" icon and sets an error message that will be displayed in a popup **when the TextView has focus**. "

One of your `EditText` receives the focus when your app is executed. The other is unfocused, therefore, the error text is not shown. That's the answer to your question.

And by the way, it **is really not a good practice** to mix namespaces: android.R.* (@android:*) and R.* (@id/*). This could result in hardly trackable bugs in not-so-distant future of your app.

Comment: But when i click into the `EditText` which is not cleared and modify its text, the error stays there...
(I did not import `android` package, i just removed it in my example. So `R.id.text1` is now in my app package. :).

Comment: On my device your above code works perfectly. I guess the problem is with the rest of your code.

Comment: There is no other code, i tested it with only this reduced example. I just noticed that the error marker is cleared, but only when the whole text is erased. Is this the intended behavior? :S

Comment: Actually I can hardly understand what you mean :) But it really sounds like intended behaviour. 1. You click a button. 2. `EditText` widgets show error message and icon. 3. Once a change to `EditText` occurs, the message and icon should get cleared.

Comment: If you want to make validation to your form, you could use a `TextWatcher`. For example, refer to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13347134/android-edittext-validation-with-textwatcher-and-seterror)

Comment: Ooops, my English is *that* bad? :( I meant the following: the red popup was removed only after i deleted the whole text from the `TextView` with backspace. If i just deleted one character, the red popup stayed, which is weird. I just tested this with two devices.

Comment: No, it's okay. From the source code it appears that when the input is empty and you trigger backspace, the objects responsible for the input logic of `TextView` (editor, keylisteners, etc) get re-initialized and the method `setError(null, null)` is called, thus disposing the error popup and drawable. So the answer is - **Yes, it is intended behaviour**. Cheers :)

Comment: Thanks for investigating! The JavaDoc says: *The icon and error message will be reset to null when any key events cause changes to the TextView's text.* :S

Comment: Yeah, seems like it's a bit underdocumented. I guess you're typing a word with a some sort of "intelligent input mode" - that is, the keyboard detects misspells, tries to propose a candidate etc. Consider it as a some sort of a "transaction" or "batch input" - the event is triggered when the batch mode is over. So if instead of "backspacing" the word you just press a "space", the error text will be gone. Check this out ;)

Comment: You are absolutely right, i am using SwiftKey. Using ASK with suggestions turned off produces the expected behavior. Thanks!